# Complex number equation, Is this logical?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I have the following question,Find the complex numbers u=x+y such that x and y are all real numbers and $u^2=−15+8i$

What I am thinking to do is solve for u but  that doesnt seem right, I am also thinking that since u is stated and it ask for $u^2$ I am thinking of doing $(-15+8i)(-15+81)$ and solve from there but still not sure if thats the right direction.

Comment: Does "complex square roots" ring a bell?

Comment: Surely you mean $u=x+yi$, not $u=x+y$.

Comment: Not to pile it on, but two real numbers add up to a real number, and that real number squares to another real number. Like @Théophile said, it looks like you meant $u = x + yi$.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way: Let $u = a+bi$, with $a$ and $b$ real. Calculate $(a+bi)^2$, equate that to $-15 + 8i$, and solve the system of equations you get, with $a$ and $b$ as the unknowns.